# Algorithm to generate simulated data for any deterministic relation

Tags: statistics

We have a statistical model (M) that we want to benchmark against simulated data; our argument is that the model M is more expressive than other models in terms of being able to capture all kinds of deterministic relations between a variable y and variables x1, x2, xn, even if these relations are very intricate. I.e. we want to show that M has a higher fit than competing models to *any kind* of *non-random relation* that might exist between y and x1, x2, xn.

Sorry if this is a naive question, but is there a general algorithm to generate non-random data for relations between y and x1, x2, xn (i.e. avoiding generating data for each known type of function between y and the x). So the only criterion is that the generated data should be non-random. We work in Matlab.

Best regards, Jean-Christophe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more expressive model comes at a cost of statistical power and risks overfitting. For example, if you have a 10,000,000 degree polynomial statistical regression model, you can fit almost any kooky set of data, as long as n<10,000,000. But so what? Observed fit is not equivalent to predictive power. Simple models, even those that are "wrong", can outperform complicated models, because the complicated models fit too much noise.

Of course, if you simply care about expressiveness, per se. Then you still need to specify what *class* of relationships its more expressive for. If you are not a mathematician, you are probably thinking of polynomials, correct? If that's the case, then you can randomly generate equations as follows:

1. Let $N\sim Poi(1)$
2. Draw a value for $N$, then draw $N+1$ values $(X_1,X_2,..,X_{N+1})$, where $X_i\sim \mathcal{N}(1,1)$
3. Assign the $X$ values to the coefficients of an $N-$degree polynomial in $x$
4. Fit your model to the chosen function, and any competing models.
5. Go back to 1

Of course, the choice of distributions above is rather arbitrary. But if you test all models against the same generated relation, at least you're stratifying on relation. The question will be if you appropriately weighted the different degrees and coefficients.

Anyway, that is my attempt to generate some non-random relations...randomly. I don't think  you can prove your model has better fit for **all** relations, as that is just too big a set of objects.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Very useful!